# Most efficient Aurelia binding way for a singleton object

Tags: javascript, data-binding, binding, aurelia

Here's a pretty fundamental JavaScript  and Aurelia question.

Let's say that I have a singleton object, for example `User` and it would often get updates from the server, which returns a whole new `User` object.

Now, to push the update to the views, I have two options (that I know of):

1. Update every property of the existing `User` to that of the new `User`'s manually (this would also require mapping every property).
2. Replace the object reference and push an `EventAggregator` notification for all listeners to re-query the `User` object.

I have currently gone for option number 1, which has raised some issues, but nothing blocking.

Which one would be more efficient and/or provide more benefits over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my opinion. You don't have to use `EventAggregator`, and you also don't have to struggle updating every property. You could create helper class (`AppState` or something) to hold your `User` object. In your elements, inject the `AppState` class and create a getter function to return the `User` object (use `@computedFrom` or `aurelia-computed` to avoid dirty-checking). For example:

JS

```
import { AppState, MyClass } from './app-state';
import { computedFrom } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyElement {

  static inject = [AppState];

  constructor(appState) {
    this.appState = appState;

  }

  @computedFrom('appState.obj')
  get obj() {
    return this.appState.obj;
  }

  updateObject() {
    this.appState.obj = new MyClass(); 
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
  <h1>Element 1</h1>
  <button click.delegate="updateObject()">Update Object</button>
  <br><br>
  ${obj.p1} 
  <br><br><br>
  ${obj.p2}
</template>
```

Running example https://gist.run/?id=f2ed9769343513b0819115863ff64c34

Comment: That's an awesome idea, I'll definitely try it out tomorrow and see how well it fits into my current structure. :)