# In Aurelia, how can one one view-model affect the bound variables of another model-view

Tags: aurelia

I would like the body of my application to be able to change a message shown in the header.

For example if header.html looks like this:

```
<template>
  ${message}
</template>
```

How could a peer view-model change that displayed 'message' variable? Or perhaps I am just going about this completely the wrong way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common solution to your scenario is to use the parent viewmodel to bridge the two peers.  Bind the same variable (either as a single variable or as an object) to both children using two-way binding.  Then, when it changes in one, it will change in the other.

**Example:**

**Parent view (parent.html)**

```
<template>
  <require from="./header"></require>
  <require from="./my-child2"></require>

  <header message.two-way="message"></header>
  <my-child2 message.two-way="message"></my-child2>
</template>
```

**Child1 viewmodel (header.js)**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
export class Header {
  @bindable message;
}
```

**Child1 view (header.html)**

```
<template>
  ${message}
</template>
```

**Child2 viewmodel (child2.js)**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
export class MyChild2 {
  @bindable message;
  attached() {
    this.message = "Greetings from MyChild2!";
  }
}
```

There are other ways to do this but hopefully this gets you on the right track so you can see how the binding works across views.

Comment: Thanks. That will do the job for me.

Comment: In the end, I actually used the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263660/most-efficient-aurelia-binding-way-for-a-singleton-object. My exact situation was better suited to storing some global state in a singleton.